# Consumen multiple network interfaces of single machine for kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-cluster

I have a Linux machine with 3 network interfaces,
let's say IPs are 192.168.1.101,192.168.1.102,192.168.1.103
I want to consume all 3 IPs of this single node to create a Kafka cluster with other nodes, Should all 3 IPs have their separate brokers?
Also using nic bonding is not recommended, all IPs need to be utilized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this... If you are using separate volumes (`log.dirs`) for each address, then maybe you'd want separate Java processes, sure, but you'd still be sharing the same memory, and having that machine be a single point of failure.

In any case, you can set one process to have `advertised.listeners` list out each of those addresses for clients to communicate with, however, you'd still have to deal with port allocations in the OS, so you might need to set `listeners` like so

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT_1://0.0.0.0:9092,PLAINTEXT_2://0.0.0.0:9093,PLAINTEXT_3://0.0.0.0:9094
```

And make sure you have `listener.security.protocol.map` setup as well using those names

Note that clients will only communicate with the leader topic-partition at any time, so if you have one broker JVM process and 3 addresses for it, then really only one address is going to be utilized. One optimization for that could be your intra-cluster replication can use a separate NIC.

Comment: I have a 2 node cluster, and want to utilize all the ports withouth creating a nic bonding, so also need any changes in zookeeper.properties?

Comment: Can't think of any, but you shouldn't run Zookeeper on the same server as the broker.